# autocomplete/typeahead angularjs bootstrap on elasticsearch

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete, elasticsearch

I was looking for a working solution to get autocomplete/typeahead with angularjs&bootstrap on elasticsearch server.

Comment: Wouldn't be better if you split this question in Question + Answer?

Comment: i split it in question / Answer ;)

Answer (score 5):

This is a working solution, not a question, but I want to share it hope it will help:

the html code to call the autocomplete function :

```
 <input required type="text"
   popover-trigger="focus"
   placeholder="recherche globale"
   class="form-control"
   ng-model="simplequeryInput"
   ng-model-onblur focus-on="focusMe"
   ng-click="searchSimple=true" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 ? submitSimple() : null"
   typeahead="item for item in autocomplete($viewValue) | limitTo:15 "
   typeahead-on-select="simplequeryInput=$model"
 />
```

- Include the elasticsearch (v2.4.0) script 
  available [here](http://pastebin.com/WhPSL54h)
- my elasticsearch service

  ```
  interfaceApp.service('elasticQuery', function ($rootScope,esFactory) {
    return esFactory({ host: $rootScope.elastic_host}); //'localhost:9200'
  });
  ```
- angularjs code querying elasticsearch :

  ```
  'use strict';
  var searchModules = angular.module('searchModules', ['ngRoute','ngDialog']);
  searchModules.controller('searchCtrl', function (ngDialog,$scope, $http,$rootScope, elasticQuery) {
    ...
    $scope.autocomplete = function(val) {
      var keywords = [];
      keywords.push(val);
      // THIS RETURN IS VERY IMPORTANT 
      return elasticQuery.search({
        index: 'YOUR_INDEX_NAME',
        size: 15,
        body: {
          "fields" : ["T_FAMILY","T_GENUS","T_SCIENTIFICNAME"], // the fields you need
          "query" : {
          "bool" : {
            "must" : [
              {
                "query_string" : {
                  "query" : "T_FAMILY:"+val // i want only source where FAMILY == val
                }
              }
            ]
          }
          }
        }
      }).then(function (response) {
        for (var i in response.hits.hits) {
          var fields = (response.hits.hits[i]).fields;
          var tmpObject = fields["T_FAMILY"] +" " + fields["T_GENUS"] + " ( "+fields["T_SCIENTIFICNAME"] + " )";
          keywords.push(tmpObject);
        }
      return keywords;
      });
    }
  });
  ```

hope it helps

Comment: Do you mind posting the html/js code for the sample?

Comment: tell me what did you need

Comment: Well I had found the way to work it from the angular-ui documentation available here:

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

But your code snippet gave me an idea of how to extract data out of the json. Vote up for that.